# Plotting with rasterio

Tags: python, matplotlib, geotiff, rasterio

I'm following the example at https://mapbox.github.io/rasterio/topics/plotting.html

And am using this geotiff file http://download.osgeo.org/geotiff/samples/spot/chicago/SP27GTIF.TIF

Here is my code:

```
import rasterio
from matplotlib import pyplot

tif_file = "SP27GTIF.TIF"
src = rasterio.open(tif_file)
pyplot.imshow(src.read(1), cmap='pink')
pyplot.show = lambda : None  # prevents showing during doctests
pyplot.show()
```

I run the code and don't get any errors, but I also don't see any plots. Any ideas?

Comment: does the plot only not show when you use rasterio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `pyplot.show = lambda : None`  assigns a lambda function to `pyplot.show`. From that point on, when calling `pyplot.show()`, the usual behviour of showing a plot is replaced by this nonsense lambda function.

Removing this line should make your plot appear as usual.